# Create an object and have it wait until it's created

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Okay here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a model object that is populated by some network data, I want to be able to create it like this:

```
// createWithID will fire off a request to a server 
MyObject *newObject = [MyObject createWithID:123];
if(newObject){
   //do something!

}
```

The problem I'm having is the network call within the createWithID method is asynchronous, so the method will always return before the call is complete.

First, is this an okay way to do this?  I like the idea of encapsulating the network call in the method.  Second, can it be done without blocking the main thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, did you just say that you ***want*** to block the main thread?!?

Comment: I agree, blocking the **MAIN** thread jams your app...

Comment: It would be better to create a new thread then add a UIActivityIndictor or something to show that the network call is in progress.

Comment: @Otium And provide some UI to cancel it, in case it's taking too long!

Comment: @ConradShultz yes of course :) or if you insist on blocking the main thread, then you can perform a synchronous network request, which I do not recommend.

Comment: just an FYI, your app is killed by the OS if you block the main thread for more than a few seconds.  It assumes that you've hung.

Comment: Whoops! Meant to say without blocking the main thread :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @danh's answer a bit, I'd say that you shouldn't have a pointer to the object until after it's all done.  For example:

```
[MyObject makeObjectWithID:123 completion:^(MyObject *object, NSError *error) {
  if (object == nil) {
    NSLog(@"error creating object: %@", error);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"created object: %@", object);
  }
}];
```

And then the creation method would be something like this:

```
+ (void)makeObjectWithID:(NSInteger)objectID completion:(void(^)(MyObject*,NSError*))handler {
  handler = Block_copy(handler);
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithID:objectID];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL succeeded = [object doTheExpensiveAndBlockingSetupThingWithError:&error];

    if (succeeded == NO) {
      [object release], object = nil;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      handler([object autorelease], error);
    });
  });
  Block_release(handler);
}
```

In principle, I find that the safer you make the API, the less likely you'll be to screw something up.  This way is safe because you never have a pointer to a partially constructed `MyObject`.  There's no way you could get one and have it *not* be fully ready to use.  Granted there's no cancellation mechanism, but you could still extend this to allow for that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, MyObject is making an asynch request to finish it's setup, so the caller cannot assume that the instance it created is ready until the asynch setup is done.

The way to solve this is to expose the caller to the knowledge that setup is done.  There are a few good approaches, including making the caller a delegate of MyObject, or having MyObject post an NSNotification when it's done, but I tend to favor blocks, because I find it often makes caller's code easier to read.

The way to do that is like this...in MyObject.h:

```
typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(id result, NSError *error);

+ (MyObject *)createWithId:(NSInteger)anId completion:(CompletionBlock)completion;
```

My object can keep the block as an ivar if it needs to (using a @property(copy...)), then invoke it when it's setup is complete.

Now the caller will look like this:

```
// do something to indicate activity, like show an activity indicator
MyObject *newObject = [MyObject createWithID:123 completion::^(id r, NSError *e) {
    // hide the activity indicator
    if (!error) {
        // code here gets executed when newObject is ready... update the ui accordingly
    }
}];

// code here gets executed right away, and should not assume that newObject is ready
```